# Sorting data into groups

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a data set where participants had to choose 3 out of 20 people (e.g. W26 means the person they chose is a 26-year old woman.) This means, that if they chose W26, M20 and W30 these variables each have the code "1" in my data, and the other 17 people get the code "0". Now I have about 200 participants that each chose 3 people. Now I want to sort the list with the following structure so that it is easy to see who chose who and what gender and age they are.

This is a sample of my data:

participant______W26___W20___M30___M21___W27___W19___M23
1______________0______0______1_____0_____1______0______1
2______________1______1______0_____0_____1______0______0
3______________0______0______0_____1_____0______0______0
etc. I have 200 participants and 20 people they can choose from (W26 etc)

This is the sort of list I want:

```
                  person1_gender person1_age    person2_gender  person2_age        
  participant 1   female         26             male           20               
  participant 2   male           32             female         19
  participant 3   male           19             male           30
```

...etc.

I have tried to do this with the if code ... which means that if the code = 1 then they should say "female" or "male" respectively, but I am actually not sure at all if I have to do other things before I use the if code.

```
 if (data$M18 > 0) 
   data$M18 = "male"
   print (data$M18)
```

The output does give me the following:

`"Warning message:
In if (data$M18 > 0) data$M18 = "male" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"`

And the data also does not change to "male" at all. Do I need to work with loops as well?

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: R Studio, sorry for not clarifying that before!

Comment: can you add sample of your data  please?

Comment: Yes, I added some data to the question